# Python function to create an oracle db insert prepared statement

Tags: python, oracle

I'm trying to insert some a record into Oracle DB table. I build a DB connector in python and have the required functions to build prepared statements, however the insert keeps failing with the error:

`"oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: DPY-4009: 0 positional bind values are required but 13 were provided"`

Here is my function:

```
    def insert(self, schema: str, table_name: str, column_names: List, values: tuple):
        """
        Inserts one row into the specified table.

        :param table_name: The name of the table to insert data into.
        :param values: A tuple containing the values to insert into a row.
        """
        column_name_placeholders = ', '.join(f'"{columns}"' for columns in column_names)
        values = self.replace_none_with_null(values)
        statement = f"INSERT INTO {schema}.{table_name} ({column_name_placeholders}) VALUES ({column_name_placeholders})"
        cursor = self.get_connection().cursor()
        cursor.execute(statement, values)
        cursor.commit()
        cursor.close()
```

I replaced 'None' values with empty strings ''. The length of list values is also equal to 13 (same as placeholders'?') including the null strings.

I created a test function to test what statement is being prepared and it does prepare the right statement:

```
INSERT INTO random_table ("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col8", "col9", "col10", "col11", "col12", "col13") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

What could I be doing wrong ?
Also, is above the best practice to create prepared statements in python or should I use binding variables ?

Comment: Could those double parenthesis in the VALUES have anything to do with the error?

Comment: @Daviid Good catch, but no that was added by mistake when I posted the Q. However, I verified in the logs the statement only has single parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to include bind value placeholders into the query.

Either using `?` for anonymous bind values:

```python
def insert(self, schema: str, table_name: str, column_names: List, values: tuple):
    """
    Inserts one row into the specified table.

    :param table_name: The name of the table to insert data into.
    :param values: A tuple containing the values to insert into a row.
    """
    assert len(column_names) == len(values), "Should have equal number of columns and values."
    column_name_placeholders = ', '.join(f'"{columns}"' for columns in column_names)     
    bind_placeholders = ', '.join("?" for _ in values)
    values = self.replace_none_with_null(values)
    statement = f'INSERT INTO "{schema}"."{table_name}" ({column_name_placeholders}) VALUES ({bind_placeholders})'
    cursor = self.get_connection().cursor()
    cursor.execute(statement, values)
    cursor.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

Or `:name` for named bind values:

```python
def insert(self, schema: str, table_name: str, column_names: List, values: tuple):
    """
    Inserts one row into the specified table.

    :param table_name: The name of the table to insert data into.
    :param values: A tuple containing the values to insert into a row.
    """
    assert len(column_names) == len(values), "Should have equal number of columns and values."
    column_name_placeholders = ', '.join(f'"{column}"' for column in column_names)     
    bind_placeholders = ', '.join(f":{column}" for column in column_names)
    values = self.replace_none_with_null(values)
    statement = f'INSERT INTO "{schema}"."{table_name}" ({column_name_placeholders}) VALUES ({bind_placeholders})'
    cursor = self.get_connection().cursor()
    cursor.execute(statement, values)
    cursor.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

*Note: In Oracle, if you are using quoted identifiers (surrounded by `"` double quotes) then you **MUST** use the correct case for the identifiers. By default, Oracle will convert unquoted identifier to UPPER-CASE so it is likely you will need to ensure that all the identifiers you pass to the function are also upper-case.*